# Installing LXDE broke my system

Tags: desktop-environments, lxde

I installed LXDE and when I rebooted all I got was a black screen. I didn't even get the screen to choose desktop environments. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

After the BIOS screen, hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> and then select the second option. Then chose `Drop to root shell` or similar (I forget precisely) and when it opens, run the command

`sudo lightdm`

or

`startx`.

Comment: i should tap shift on GRUB?

Comment: hold it down through the boot process.

Comment: After GRUB or before?

Comment: Before, so it opens GRUB

Comment: I get GRUB always

Comment: OK, chose the second option - recovery mode.

Comment: I will try and tell you

Comment: I am not getting any drop to root shell option

Comment: In advanced options for Ubuntu I don't get drop to root shell

Comment: It should `Drop to root shell prompt`. What are the options you can see?

Comment: There are some very big options

Comment: What do you mean? Can you take a photo and link to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15011/discussion-between-ritik-and-tim).